# Sorting values from values from another table php

Tags: php, mysql

My first post here.

I am trying to sort values displayed from my products table with values inside my products_categories table.

my products table contains the following fields:

```
id | psku | pname | pdescription
```

My products_categories table has the following fields:

```
id | psku | subcategory | orderid
```

The site I am building is a small eshop, which contains several subcategories. The setup at this time allows me to have 1 product added to multiple categories.

For example, product sku# 6001 would be listed in 2 subcategories, cosmetics & eyelashes. I would have then 2 entries in my products_subcategories table like so:

```
id | psku | subcategory | orderid
1 | 6001 | cosmetics | 1
2 | 6004 | eyelashes | 1
3 | 6003 | cosmetics | 2
4 | 6011 | cosmetics | 3
5 | 6020 | eyelashes | 2
6 | 6045 | cosmetics | 4
```

I am currently using the following query to display data in each subcategory:

```
SELECT * FROM products LEFT JOIN products_subcategories 
ON products.psku = products_subcategories.psku 
WHERE products.psku IN ('6001','6003','6011','6020','6045') 
GROUP BY e2o_products_subcategories.psku 
ORDER BY e2o_products_subcategories.orderid ASC
```

This should display my result as so:

```
Cosmetics:
PSKU 6001
PSKU 6003
PSKU 6011
PSKU 6045

eyelashes:
PSKU 6004
PSKU 6020
```

It doesn't seem to work. Tried some other combinations, with worst result. The products show, but will not sort by orderid

Would someone have a possible solution to this problem. I can provide sample data if needed.

Thank you.

Comment: Side note: You can improve performance with better normalization. For your sanity, as well. Change `products.id` to `products.product_id`, `products_categories.id` to `products_categories.product_category_id`, and `product_categories.pksu` to `product_categories.product_id`. Then join on product_id rather than pksu.

Comment: What is the `e2o_` prefix in your order by and group by clauses?

Comment: hi, sorry for the prefix. this was a leftover from an older code. forgot to remove. thanks for the explanation. makes sense to do it this way. better to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a look at the sampledata.php file that you have created. I am struggling to make sense of what you are trying to do. Why are you running two queries? Surely you could achieve the same result with a single query.

Your first query will return a list of pskus that you are then passing into the second query -

```
SELECT psku, subcategory
FROM products_subcategories
WHERE subcategory = 'cosmetics'

+------+-------------+
| psku | subcategory |
+------+-------------+
| 6018 |  cosmetics  |
| 6017 |  cosmetics  |
| 6022 |  cosmetics  |
| 6025 |  cosmetics  |
+------+-------------+
```

The second query is then -

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.*
FROM e2o_products
INNER JOIN e2o_products_subcategories 
    ON e2o_products.psku = e2o_products_subcategories.psku 
WHERE e2o_products.pstatus =  '1' 
AND e2o_products.psku IN (6018,6017,6022,6025)
GROUP BY e2o_products.psku
ORDER BY e2o_products_subcategories.dsporder DESC
```

Given that you are only retrieving the fields from the products table you can just do -

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
INNER JOIN products_subcategories ps
    ON p.psku = ps.psku 
WHERE p.pstatus = 1
AND ps.subcategory = '$subcat'
ORDER BY ps.dsporder DESC
```

Comment: Beautiful! Exactly what I wanted. Thank you for making the query shorter and cleaner. Fantastic solution, very fast response. Thanks also to everyone else involved.

Cheers all!

Answer (score 1):

You need to order on the subcategory name first, so

```
SELECT * FROM products 
    LEFT JOIN products_subcategories 
    ON products.psku = products_subcategories.psku 
WHERE products.psku IN ('6001','6003','6011','6020','6045') 
ORDER BY e2o_products_subcategories.subcategory ASC,
         e2o_products_subcategories.orderid ASC
```

Note I've also removed your GROUP BY as with it you will only get each PSKU returned once in the results and you won't confidently be able to predict which subcategory will be returned for PSKU's in multiple categories. If every product has an entry in the subcategories table you probably want to change the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @daespo Why does the product display multiple times without it? Can you post an example? That doesn't sound right. It should display as many times as categories it belongs to.

Comment: Hi. Would it help if I post some sample data?
The testing site is at: http://e2o.aiiic.com
If you look at the sub categories, you might see what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @daespo Yes, definitely post some sample data.

Comment: Hi liquorvicar,
Thanks again for your reply. I have uploaded sample data here:
http://e2o.aiiic.com/helpneeded/sampledata.php
I hope this is enough.

Looking for to your reply. Thank you!